# Zip folder and its contents

Tags: python, zip

I want to zip the folder 'com.facebook.katana' and its contents. The directory structure looks like this:

```
    AndroidBags
    Downloads
     ├── com.facebook.katana
     │     ├── one.txt
     │     └── two.txt
     │     ├── Data
     │     └── PetController.java
```

I want to create this .zip file into the `./AndroidBags/` Here is my code to zip my files :

```
def retrieve_file_paths(dirName):
    # setup file paths variable
    filePaths = []

    # Read all directory, subdirectories and file lists
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(dirName):
        for filename in files:
            # Create the full filepath by using os module.
            filePath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            filePaths.append(filePath)

    # return all paths
    return filePaths


# Declare the main function
def main():
    # Assign the name of the directory to zip
    dir_name = 'mydir'

    # Call the function to retrieve all files and folders of the assigned directory
    filePaths = retrieve_file_paths(dir_name)

    # printing the list of all files to be zipped
    print('The following list of files will be zipped:')
    for fileName in filePaths:
        print(fileName)

    # writing files to a zipfile
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(dir_name + '.zip', 'w')
    with zip_file:
        # writing each file one by one
        for file in filePaths:
            zip_file.write(file)

    print(dir_name + '.zip file is created successfully!')
```

My problem is that when I create the zip file I have a './Downloads' folder created. How can I remove it to have directly 'com.facebook.katana' and the files it contains when I unzip it in AndroidBags folder ?

Thank you

Comment: that is because you are zipping the Download Folder. just need to open "Download" in your code.

Comment: What do you mean by open "Download" in your code ?

Comment: in ur code, check the current path before it tried to zip the files, I am pretty sure it is outside the Download Folder.